# C# Calculating download speed correctly when dowloading with multiple threads

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to show to user correct download speed but my app downloads are bunch of small files at the same time and to speed things up I'm using `Parallel.ForEach`. However I can't calculate correct download speed. With my current code I'm basically calculating average download speed not the speed currently downloading. Because it updates UI every time download is completed. When I use normal `foreach` I can calculate correctly but then speed is slow. How can I show correctly the downloaded Mbps with multiple threads and multiple files ?

Note: This app is WPF but I hardly used any MVVM. This is my first time using WPF at the moment I'm just trying to make good looking something with decent functioning.

**Download Function**

```
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            DownloadController.stopwatch.Start();
            DownloadController.IsDownloadStarted = true;
            DownloadController.IsDownloadInProgress = true;
            Parallel.ForEach(downloadList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, file =>
            {
                try
                {
                    DownloadController.LastDownloadingFileName = file.FileName;
                    GET_DownloadFile(file.FileName, file.LastUpdate.UnixTimeStampToDateTime()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    logger.Info("Download", file.FileName, "Downloading file completed");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lock (_failedDownloads)
                    {
                        _failedDownloads.Add(file);
                    }
                    logger.Exception(ex, "Download", file.FileName, file.LastUpdate, file.Size, $"Failed to download file");
                }
            });
```

**Progress Changed Event**

```
public static void DownloadProgressChangedEvent(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            MainWindow._dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                ButtonProgressAssist.SetValue(MainWindow.This.Prog_Downloading, ProgressValue);
                ButtonController.ButtonPlay_Downloading();
                if (e.ProgressPercentage == 100)
                {
                    DownloadedSize += e.TotalBytesToReceive;
                    var downloadSpeed = string.Format("{0} ", (DownloadedSize / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.0"));
                    var text1 = $"({ProgressValue}% - {DownloadedFileCount}/{TotalFileUpdateCount}) @ {downloadSpeed}MB/s {EasFile.GetFileNameWithExtension(LastDownloadingFileName)} ";
                    MainWindow.This.DownloadTextBlock.Text = text1;
                }
            }));

        }
```

**ProgressCompletedEvent**

```
public static void DownloadProgressCompletedEvent(object? sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.Cancelled)
            {
                DownloadedFileCount++;
            }
        }
```

I tried to use `PerformanceCounter` to watch my current app's network usage but it only shows me the usage of all usage on specific network.

Comment: Just print "about three fiddy remaining", increment the progress bar to 90% in one-second increments and move it to 100% when complete. This is a decades old problem that you aren't going to solve. If you don't know on beforehand how many bytes you'll need to download, you can never give an accurate estimate.

Comment: You can create a `Progress` class and track the state of total downloaded bytes in this class in a threadsafe manner, but unless your downloads take a really long time, showing an indeterminate progressbar in the UI usually suffices.

Comment: @CodeCaster i do know how many bytes each download going to be.

Comment: @mcy mostly downloads about 200 300MB around 20 files. But client also can download about 7000+ files in one go depending on client has all files or not.

Comment: So, keep progress per file?

Comment: Use Events or Observables for each task which updates that tasks' progress.  On the listener side, it simply takes in each event and determines totals.  It too can use events to update the progress bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices here:
First way is to create a class that will handle the single file downloading. In this class you should count the bytes downloaded. One possible solution for this is to have a member which is cleared every second. The received bytes should be added to it. Before it's clearing the class should report that value to the main class where it should be a member act in the same way for all currently downloading files.
The other solution is instead of having a class on every progress event to report the received bytes and the time. In the main class you should have a list which will store that pairs. Then on every second you can get only the records for last second and aggregate the received bytes.

P.S. Accessing the members should be thread safe in both ways.

Comment: I tried your second suggestion but i have to lock the list to make it safe to add items. There i wasnt sure what to do. I will try first suggestion

Comment: I went with first suggestion and it worked. Thank you very much.

For further help if anybody come to this problem. Need 2 seperate classes. One will be static which will handle total progress and one will be class and everytime you start download you create new instance of that class and add the events inside that class. Events must be in that class. So that will handle single file downloading. Then its simple check bytes downloaded with every download progress and create Invoke methods inside static class and update UI accordingly. Also you may need to know total download size.